# How to suppress the MouseMove event in particular case?

Tags: events, visual-studio-2005, suppress

My issue is that I need to change the mouse pointer's position within the MouseMove event, which causes infinite recursion. I need to suppress the MouseMove event which `Me.Cursor.Position = newpos` generates. How can I do that?

I read about `Me.EnableEvents = False` but this is not valid for Visual Studio 2005 and I could not find an equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do?  Maybe there's a better way.  But assuming this is what you want, you could unsubscribe the event handler in your `MouseMove` event before changing the cursor position using `RemoveHandler`.  Just add it back when you're done:

```
Public Class MyForm

    Private Sub MyForm_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) _
            Handles Me.MouseMove

        UnsubscribeEvents()

        ' change mouse pointer's position here...

        ResubscribeEvents()
    End Sub

    Private Sub UnsubscribeEvents()
        RemoveHandler Me.MouseMove, AddressOf MyForm_MouseMove
    End Sub

    Private Sub ResubscribeEvents()
        AddHandler Me.MouseMove, AddressOf MyForm_MouseMove
    End Sub

End Class
```